# How to set up a workflow using Split, Aggregate and a single thread (3.11 migration issue)

Tags: java, multithreading, apache-camel

I'm having issues migrating to Camel 3.21 from the 3.2 version.

My workflow looks like this:

read an XML file from FS -> parse it and **split** it into pieces -> **aggregate** those pieces into chunks of certain size -> process chunks one by one

One of the requirements is that the next file must not be read while the previous one hasn't been completely processed.

With the old Camel version everything worked well, but with 3.21 (I guess the breaking changes were introduced in 3.11) the next file is being read while the previous one is still being processed.

I found that now there are two different threads, one performs the actual aggregation, and the other one processes the aggregated chunks. That lets the first thread go ahead and read files regardless of what the second thread does.

I tried to follow the instructions from Camel docs:

> In order to achieve synchronous aggregation, use an instance of **SynchronousExecutorService** for the executorService option. The aggregated output will execute in the same thread that called the aggregator.

Now I have the only thread gathering the chunks and processing them (bingo!), but the issue is that it doesn't get back to compiling the second chunk when the processing of the first one is completed. It just hangs and does nothing.

My guess is that this change in 3.11 is what causes the issue:

> The aggregate EIP will now always use a worker thread pool for processing outgoing messages. Previously a worker pool was only created when parallelProcessing=true. When having parallelProcessing=false then a single-threaded worker pool is created and used by the aggregator.
> Camels routing engine works better when a dedicated worker pool that eliminates a **hack** that otherwise was needed in other EIPs that was affected if using the aggregator in some special configurations.

Any ideas on how to solve that are highly appreciated!